# How to get brown tops to my garlic knots

Tags: oven, heat, rolls

I've found some good recipes for garlic knots, but can't get them to have that restaurant style brown tops to them.  The best I can do is get them slightly brown at the top if I cook them longer than expected, on the verge of burning the bottoms.  I have the same problem with pizza crusts too and some other rolls I've tried in the past.

Is there a tip to get these to brown better in a regular home oven?

Comment: what temperature are you baking them at, and for how long?

Comment: The recipe calls for 20 minutes at 450, though I I've tinkered with it a bit and take it out a bit earlier.  I've tried it with a bit of lower temp, maybe 425 or 400

Answer (score 7):

The usual tips for browning the tips of baked goods:

- move them higher in the oven, so there’s more top heat
- a milk wash, butter, or something with protein or sugar to brown
- Add sugar or protein to the dough
- Add baking soda to the dough (because acids inhibit browning, bases promote it)

… but I would avoid that first one for garlic knots.  Burned garlic is not good.  And I assume they’re covered in butter already, so you will likely need to adjust the dough.

Comment: Is it just as simple as adding a bit more sugar or adding baking soda to the dough? Would I need to worry about any of the other recipe's ratios in it like reducing the flour or add a bit more water?

Comment: Regarding the wash, in a lot of recipes it's egg wash, it does the browning as well!

Comment: @gdawgrancid : if baking soda, just add a little, as it can be soapy in large amounts. You might be able to mix with water and brush it on, as pretzels don’t have it all the way through the dough, but you usually have a butter wash with garlic knots, and I don’t know what would happen if you added baking soda to the butter.  For the sugar, yes, just try adding a tablespoon to your dough; milk powder might also work (adds protein).  You shouldn’t need to adjust liquid

Answer (score 1):

Brushing the tops with an egg wash helps to get these to brown better in a regular home oven. Also, you can try placing the baking sheet closer to the upper heat in the oven.

Comment: Please don’t repeat what others have written.